# Drawing bitmaps in android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

I am making an android app just to test for myself. I am trying to draw a bitmap image using canvas, but why isn't it working? It just closes itself a second after startup without any exceptions.

This is the code that i am using so far:

```
package com.mysoftwaremobileapps.BitmapExample;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

public class BitmapExampleActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private ArrayList<CustomImageViewActivity> CustomImages;
Bitmap ImageView1;
float x;
float y;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Canvas c = new Canvas();
    drawImage(c);
}
public void doDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    for (CustomImageViewActivity p: CustomImages) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(ImageView1, p.getX(), p.getY(), null);
}

}
public void drawImage(Canvas canvas)
{
    ImageView1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    Paint black;
    black = new Paint();
    black.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    black.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), black);
    canvas.drawBitmap(ImageView1, null, null);

    //Parachuter nr.1
    x = 14;
    y = 28;

    CustomImageViewActivity p = new CustomImageViewActivity(x, y);
    CustomImages.add(p);
    Canvas c1 = new Canvas();
    doDraw(c1);
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        for (CustomImageViewActivity p: CustomImages) {
            p.posX = event.getX();
            p.posY = event.getY();
    }
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: `Canvas c = null;doDraw(c);` you are passing null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Canvas c = null;
```

Plz initialize it

```
Canvas c = new Canvas();
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that when you call doDraw you're passing in a null reference to a canvas.

To achieve your goal, you could extend a View and override the onDraw method of the View class.  That will allow you to draw on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

According to your log, the error is on line 28. Check no further: you initialized your Canvas variable as null, therefore it's obvious that the NullPointerException happens while you try to access one of its methods.

I suggest you another way to draw stuff into an Activity: subclass a View and use the onDraw() method which provides you a Canvas.